# OpenCV won't open some videos of many videos of the same format

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, mp4

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with OpenCV 2.4.6.

I have 4 videos that I recorded one by one with my Nokia Lumia 920. OpenCV won't open .mp4 format from my phone by the default. So I converted all these 4 videos using Sony Vegas to .mp4 with the SAME preferences for all of them. Now the problem is that OpenCV has a problem to open two of them. The other two works like a charm with no problem. Below is the information about codec that I used (Yes, it is the same for all videos):

[image: Codec info]

And this is the error:

[image: Error]

Why is it so that they are the same type but only a few of them are loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is a crash? If so, the answer is pretty simple: there's a bug in codec, from the name of the DLL I think that's ffmpeg H264 codec. You should try to update it, or just avoid it.