# OpenCV won't open the same videofile as opened before

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I have a problem to load a videofile. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV 2.4.6.

Sometimes it loads video properly and sometimes it won't, although it is the **same file** and the **same code** (Nothing has changed). So basically, one day it works and the next day does not. I noticed some strange behavior [BEFORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307057/opencv-wont-open-some-videos-of-many-videos-of-the-same-format).

When I run the code I get **Unhandled exception**

---

[image]

---

and then **No source available**

---

[image]

---

A few weeks ago I wasn't able to open a video in one of my project. The problem was that if I opened a project from pinned Start menu than the video couldn't be loaded.

[image]

**BUT** when I opened a solution right from a directory than video was loaded properly. I couldn't believe so I tried this more times.

However, in either case it does not work this time.

ALso, I tried to run Visual Studio as admin. Nothing.

What could be a problem here?

Comment: What happens when you use this Files with FFMPEG from the command line? Try e.g. `ffmpeg -i video_input.avi video_output.mpg` multiple times. If this works we know that your ffmpeg installation and the video files are ok and the error has to be in the code.

Comment: I've installed OpenCV using the pre-built libraries. There are no ffmpeg executables, only .dll files.

Comment: Ok... can you play the video files without problems using VLC? If the Answer is yes pleae show us a minimal example code where this error occurs. Maybe you are doing something wrong ;)

Comment: Yes. The video itself is not a problem. I can play it even with a built-in media player. The code fails at `CvCapture* cap = cvCreateFileCapture("video.mp4");` or `VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");` when replaced.

Comment: I know that there has been a lot of bugs in the h264 decoder but afaik most of them were fixed.. you could however try to install the newest OpenCv build 2.4.7. Otherwise this question seem to better fit either in the OpenCv or the FFMPEG community as there can´t be a problem with your code if the error occurs inside the opencv function (that you use correctly).